# render custom json array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, response

Here I have array of Hours in @hours now with relation of user and hour_type.

Hours_controller.rb

```
def index
  @houra = Hour.all
  @users = User.where(id: @hours.map(&:user_id).uniq)
  @hour_type = HourType.where(id: @hours.map(&:hour_type_id).uniq)
  render json: {
    users: [@users],
    hour_type: [@hour_type],
    hours: @hours
  }
end
```

this above code is give me response like below.

```
{
  "users": [
    "id": 6
  ],
  "hour_type": [
    "id": 69
  ],
  "hours": [
    {
      "id": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
    }
  ]
}
```

But Now I want a response in json like below.

```
{
  "users":[
    0:{
      user_id:2
    },
    1:{
      user_id:3
    },
  ],
"hours":[
0:[
  {
    hour_type_id:"1"
    hours: [
      {
        hour_id: 1
      },

        hour_id: 2
      },
    ]
  },
1:[
  {
    hour_type_id:"1"
    hours: [
      {
        hour_id: 1
      },
      {
        hour_id: 2
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

What can I do to get same response in json?

Here I am adding some what near to result i got

```
  @hours = Hour.all
  @users = User.where(id: @hours.map(&:user_id).uniq)
  @hour_types = HourType.where(id: @hours.map(&:hour_type_id).uniq)

  result = {
    users: @users,
    hours: []
  }

  @hour_types.each do |hour_type|
    hour_type_hash = {
      hour_type: hour_type,
      hours: Hour.where(hour_type_id: hour_type.id).all
    }
    result[:hours] << hour_type_hash
  end
```

render json: result

Now just want to add id before user

Comment: “What can I do to get same response in json”—you can write the code that will produce json.

Comment: i have tryed most of the case but i can not get same output like this @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: Can you show how `@hours` looks? Is it the same structure? Is the question how to get from hash to json, or to correctly map your data to the required format/order/nesting in the json? In which case we definitely need to see how the data looks to help you with that transformation.

Comment: please read que again @nathanvda

Comment: Thanks for the update, your question is much clearer now. Wow: the requested format is sooooo wierd. I am presuming the numbers indicating the position in the array are a kind of comments, not requested, right? Because otherwise it would not make sense, afaik an array in json cannot have an index/position?

Comment: In the wanted structure "hour_type_id" and "hours" are combined, and in your original you just list all "hour-types" and "hours": what is the relation/reasoning to combine them? Does an hour belong to an hour_type?

Comment: relation like this: User has many Hours, hour has many hour_type @nathanvda

Comment: More of a pattern recommendation, but for complex and non-standard payloads you should look into using serializers like https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi. It'll give you a nice arena for formatting your json, separate from the rest of your controller logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty naive way to render it, but this should get you started:

```
@hours = Hour.all
@users = User.where(id: @hours.map(&:user_id).uniq)
@hour_types = HourType.where(id: @hours.map(&:hour_type_id).uniq)

result = {
  users: @users.map{|u| {user_id: u.id} },
  hours: [] 
} 

@hour_types.each do |hour_type| 
  hour_type_hash = { 
    hour_type_id: hour_type.id, 
    hours: Hour.where(hour_type_id: hour_type.id).all.map{|h| {hour_id: h.id} } 
  }
  result[:hours] << hour_type_hash  
end 

render json: result_hash
```

Comment: I tried this but its show me syntex error in this line users: @users.map{|u| user_id: u.id},

Comment: Right, this is of course untested code. Doh. We should make it more explicit we are creating/returning a hash. It should now work? (I changed/fixed it in two places). Does it work now?